# Getting "pangoxft library not found" error when configuring wxWidgets

Tags: apt, unicode, configure, wxpython, pango

I'm trying to configure wxWidgets 3.0.4 on Ubuntu 18.10:

```
$ ./configure --with-x11
```

But getting an error when running the config script:

```
checking for PANGOXFT... configure: error: pangoxft library not found, library cannot be compiled in Unicode mode
```

Is there an apt package containing the missing library, if yes, what is the exact name of it?

---

*Offtopic: can anyone with reputation > 300 create a new tag "wxwidgets" and add it to the tags (or maybe replace "wxpython" if there is a limitation that the number of tags must be < 5)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to

```
sudo apt install libpango1.0-dev
```